# Use Gulp to modify the html tag

Tags: html, gulp, html5-appcache, gulp-inject

We use Gulp in our build process and it works great.  We use gulp-inject to inject CSS and JS files into our index.html using the syntax:

```
<!-- inject:css -->
```

Is there a way I can inject an attribute in the html tag?  In our dev environment we want to have just

```
<html>
```

In production we want to add the manifest tag to point to our appcache file:

```
<html manifest="/myapp.appcache">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dom.